# Information regarding who to contact for submitting books to software centre

Tags: software-center, ebooks

I am wondering who I need to get in touch with to find out information regarding books in the Ubuntu Software Centre. What are the requirements? Does Ubuntu get a percentage regarding the sale (like apples app store) and who do we need to submit it to? I am interested in doing manuals and novels for the Ubuntu Software Centre since I wish to support the idea.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to get your books, magazines, games, applications, etc into the Ubuntu Software Center is to go to https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com, register, and submit a new application. The developer agreement is found at https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/dev/tos/ and *should* answer your questions.

IF you do have questions about submissions or anything else related to paid applications/content on the Ubuntu Software Center, simply reach out to john dot pugh at canonical.

For more detail go to http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that wishes to publish an application on the Ubuntu Software Center simply go to [software-center.ubuntu.com](https://software-center.ubuntu.com/dev) and submit your application!

Also have a look at [developer.ubuntu.com](http://developer.ubuntu.com/). The main page shows:

> Bring your apps to Ubuntu
>
> Ubuntu is the third most popular desktop operating system in the world. Find out everything you need to know to start developing and publishing your apps on Ubuntu.

1 thing: it looks like books in USC are from well known companies and/or long time running online magazines. You probably need to have several issues ready for submission to show you are dedicated.

Comment: I probably should answer this one before upvoting right? ;)